# Using [(value)] instead [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular

I am checking angular examples and stuck at `[(ngModel)]` as seen link below.
How can I use `[(value)]` instead `[(ngModel)]`  ?

```html
<div *ngIf='!editMode' (click)='editMode=true' class='cell'>
    {{currency}} {{ data | number:'':'en' }}
</div>
<input *ngIf='editMode'
       (focusout)="onFocusOut()"
       (keydown.enter)='$event.target.blur()'
       [(ngModel)]='data'
       class='cellInput'
       type='number'
       (focusout)="editMode=false">
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inline-edit-cy7adf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit-input%2Fedit-input.component.html)

Comment: Like this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inline-edit-uq3me8?

Comment: what do you want actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ngModel is a directive that allows your input to participate in a
  form (but works also without a form)
- value is a property you can bind a value to with [value]="name" while
  (valueChange)="..." doesn't work, because the  element doesn't
  have an @Output() valueChange; therefore  [(value)]="..." is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you will not be able to obtain the ngModel directive and ngForm directive binding which can offer you some of the validations via referencing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question? Are you asking if you can use `value` in place of `ngModel`? like this

```html
<input
  *ngIf="editMode"
  type="number"
  class="cellInput" 
  (focusout)="onFocusOut()"
  (keydown.enter)="$event.target.blur()"
  (focusout)="editMode=false" 
  [(value)]="data"
>
```

If so the answer is no. Angular invokes two-way binding to html inputs with `ngModel`. But the input value property is what angular is binding to the `ngModel` variable (i.e. `data`).

Otherwise please elaborate on your question. Thanks